# Does the IPPCV package that's bundled with OpenCV 3.0 include ALL possible ipp related improvements to the running of OpenCV functions?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, opencv3.0, intel-ipp

Whilst building OpenCV 3.0 from source, using cmake, I'm not sure whether the ipp (intel integrated performance improvements) version provided in the 3rdparty directory includes all ipp related performance improvements, or if there is more to gain by linking to the (more complete) ipp directory contained within the intel student Parallel Studios XE cluster edition I have installed on my system.

For example, I have noticed that the lib directory for the ipp that comes bundled with OpenCV includes only one .lib file (ippicvmt.lib), whereas the lib directory for ipp in parallel studios contains many more .lib files (16 in total).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot,
Dan

Comment: maybe this one helps: http://answers.opencv.org/question/68072/list-of-which-functions-use-ippcv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

First of all `ippicv` included to OpenCV contatins optimizations only for AVX2 and SSE4.2. Whilst full IPP package from Parallel Studio contatins optimization for all supported platforms.

Also you can get additional benefit of using full IPP library since some functions are not in `ippicv`. For example, `cv::filter2D`.
Unfortunately I don't know how automatically get the list of this functions, but you can search lines like:

```
#if !defined(HAVE_IPP_ICV_ONLY)
```

It indicated that code inside works only with full IPP library.